# Modify DataFrame column values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to modify the formatting of the strings of a Datframe column according to a condition.

Here is an example of the file

[The DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgYk0.jpg)

Now, as you might see, the object column values either start with http or a capital letter: I want to make it so that:

1. if the string starts with http, I put it between <>
2. if the string starts with a capital letter, I format it as " + string + " + '@en'

However, I cant seem to be able to do so: I tried to make a simple if condition with .startswith(h) or contains('http') but it doesn't work, because I understand that it actually returns a list of booleans instead of a single condition.
Maybe it is very simple but I cannot solve, any help is appreciated.

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
ont1 = pd.read_csv('1.tsv',sep='\t',names=['subject','predicate','object'])
ont1['subject'] = '<' + ont1['subject'] + '>'
ont1['predicate'] = '<' + ont1['predicate'] + '>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you have many of the right pieces here, you mentioned boolean indexing which is what you can use to select and update certain rows, for example I'll do this on a dummy DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["http://akjsdhka", "Helloall", "http://asdffa", "Bignames", "nonetodohere"]})
```

First we can find rows starting with "http":

```
mask = df["a"].str.startswith("http")
df.loc[mask, "a"] = "<" + df["a"] + ">"
```

Then we update the rows where that mask is true, and the same for the other condition:

```
mask2 = df["a"].str[0].str.isupper()
df.loc[mask2, "a"] = "\"" + df["a"] + "\"@en"
```

Final result:

```
                   a
0  <http://akjsdhka>
1      "Helloall"@en
2    <http://asdffa>
3      "Bignames"@en
4       nonetodohere
```

Comment: Thank you Sven, this clearly answered my question and it also added a nice explanation. One question though: when I transform my dataframe in a .csv file with , the column modified with your code inexplicably moves from e.g., "A Master's or PhD thesis."@en to  """A Master's or PhD thesis.""@en". Is this somehow related to the way I concatenated the string for that condition?

Comment: @EnricoBignotti this will be something to with whether or not there already exist `"` characters in your string or if the `"` symbols just denote that this is a string. In my answer I added an additional `"` to the start and end of the part before `@en` using `\"`. Try experimenting with removing that like `df["a"] + "@en"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
ont1.loc[['subject'].str.startsWith("http"),'subject'] = "<" + ont1 ['subject'] + ">"

Ref to read:

https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/